# What skill proficiencies can a Variant Human choose from at character creation?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, skills, proficiency, human

When creating a variant human you get an extra skill to be proficient in. Does that skill have to be from your class skill list, or can it be any skill available to any class? For instance, if I'm playing a variant human barbarian, can I take acrobatics as my extra skill?

Comment: Related: [Can a human variant take proficiency in initiative?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/154494/33569)

Answer (score 15):

### With the Variant Human Traits option, you get to choose one skill of your choice, period.

The D&D 5e PHB on p. 31 states:

> ***Skills.*** You gain proficiency in one skill of your choice.

That is the end of the description of this option. If there were meant to be a restriction to your character's class list of skills, it would say so. But the text mentions nothing about class skill lists. So, there is no such restriction.

Comment: Underwater basket weaving, here I come!

Comment: @liori That would be Tool Proficiency, not a Skill Proficiency.

Answer (score 7):

The [Variant Human](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/human#VariantHuman) optional rule includes the following text (*Player's Handbook* pg. 31):

> ***Skills.*** You gain proficiency in one skill of your choice.

It is a skill of your choice, it can be any skill from the skills list regardless of what you have chosen as your class.